# Unity Play Mode with Holographic Remoting---Failed to enable remoting runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I want to use Holographic Remoting to stream holographic content to HoloLens 2 in real time. I follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/preview-and-debug-your-app?tabs=openxr) to preview my work with Holographic Remoting. But when I click the 'play' button in unity, I get this error in unity

```
Failed to enable remoting runtime.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Microsoft.MixedReality.OpenXR.Remoting.PlayModeRemotingPlugin:HookGetInstanceProcAddr (intptr) (at Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.openxr@a4cc3ecd3f67/Runtime/FeaturePlugins/PlayModeRemotingPlugin.cs:77)
UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRGeneralSettings:AttemptInitializeXRSDKOnLoad () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.management@4.2.0/Runtime/XRGeneralSettings.cs:148)
```

The Holographic Remoting App in Hololens2 had no response.
[This figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRQW2.png) shows my setting and versions of unity, openXR plugin, Mixed Reality OpenXR Plugin. How can I solve it? Thanks!

The figure about "[XR Plug-in Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecle7.png)" and "[OpenXR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3skL9.png)"

Comment: I have the same configuration but cannot reproduce this issue. Would you also share a screenshot of "XR Plug-in Management" page? It is above the "OpenXR" tab.

Comment: Hi Seth, I try again on another computer with the same windows version, and the Holographic Remoting and Play mode can work. I copy this project to my computer and it doesn't work again. The same error happens.

Moreover, the project has no extra assets. I just follow the tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/preview-and-debug-your-app?tabs=openxr) to import Mixed Rreality OpenXp Plugin and MRTK foundation using the Microsoft Mixed Reality Feature Tool. @SethDU-MSFT

Comment: Also, I attached the screenshot about "XR Plug-in Management" and "OpenXR" on the original question. I don't know what caused this error.  @SethDU-MSFT

Comment: Currently I have the same configuration as yours and this issue cannot be reproduced. Please try "Reimport All" in the project window of Unity or do a clean re-install of Unity. I have a blank MR test project on https://github.com/sethdu0525/MR-Blank-Project, and you may try the remote to see if this issue can be reproduced.

Comment: @SethDU-MSFT My unity hub has [one problem like this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1825109/a-javascript-error-occurred-in-the-main-process-af.html), so I need open unity hub as administrator to solve this problem. I suspect there is a connection between this problem and my holographic remoting problem. I try to solve this problem and after it was solved, the Holographic Remoting and Play mode can work!!

I follow these two steps to solve the unity hub problem:

Comment: 1. Set the %TEMP% and %TMP% in user variables of Environment Variables from %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp to %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp; %SystemRoot%\TEMP. Then run the unity hub, but it will not work.

2. Change the %TEMP% and %TMP% back. Then run the unity hub again, it can work without administrator.
Then when I open the same project, Holographic Remoting and Play mode can work. I don't know the reason........
I did something, but finally, none of the settings have changed. Do you have any ideas? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: This is a Unity setup issue and usually a clean install should fix this issue. You may uninstall Unity Hub + Unity 2020.3.x.  Rebooting and reinstalling it again. You can also post a thread on https://answers.unity.com/index.html to have dedicated support.